# How to assign multidimensional array to class as argument?

Tags: php, smarty

If I try to assign a multidimensional array to a class i get this error

```
            {Widgets->Widget
                    media='videos'
                    filters=Array('a' => 'b', 'c' => 'd')
            }

 "{assign var='X' value = Array('a' =&gt; 'b', 'c' =&gt; 'd')}" - Unexpected " => ", expected one of: "","" , ")"'

this doesn't work as well
            filters['a']='b'
            filters['c'] = 'd'
```

is there a way to circumvent this limit? 
the version of smarty I'm using is the latest.

the documentation isn't very clear about it:
http://www.smarty.net/docs/en/advanced.features.objects.tpl

regards

Comment: ok, i found an idiotic way to accomplish this by creating 2 arrays filters_keys = 'a' filters_values='b' and then array_combine them

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure if it is even possible to assign an array in smarty template.
I did always circumvent this by instantiating an array in PHP code - then You can assign it to an object in PHP - and after that call $smarty->assign("object", $objectWithArray);

Comment: sure, but that's a widget i made with the intent to allow designer to build modules on the flight. so i have a huge class in php that accepts parameters and renders an output

Comment: Still there must be a way how to call PHP to do that for Smarty... I don't like any value assigning in smarty - smarty should be only for presenting of information and dislaying layouts, so You'd to do all Your logic within Your PHP code...

If it has some action being called from template on user input or so it is a place to do that...

Comment: I'm aware of that, the logic is in the PHP safe and sound. smarty is just passing arguments to a class, this class then parses another template and renders the output. it's just an easier way to delegate the work to the designers, if parameters aren't alright i throw out an exception until they make it clear

Comment: So could you instead of assigning in smarty send all the simple attributes to the PHP and there construct an array that will be assigned to an object in PHP?

Comment: I want designers to be able to pull out data, it's 5 years i'm passing them variables and arrays, i'm trying to work the other way around